# Installing windows 7 on a new Samsung 840 EVO SSD

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, ssd

I was replacing a broken HDD with a Samsung 840 EVO SSD. The instructions were all images as if it was a piece of furniture, with no instructions for a blank install, so obviously something went wrong.

I just replaced the drives, used a USB to install windows, however I am having driver problems, specifically the network (cant connect to networks) and graphics (can't run 1600x900 anymore), I assume there are more that aren't working though. The laptop is a Toshiba Satellite L775.

I'm not sure if the downloads here: www.samsung.com/samsungssd are the drivers so before carrying on I wanted to ask a few questions to make sure I don't screw it up any further, because the instructions on the ssd website are non-existent.

1. Are these drivers or what, if not where can I get the drivers, and why did it go wrong?
2. Can I install these drivers in my new installation of windows or will I need to clear it and start again, if so how do I do that?
3. Id prefer to not have to make a DVD for the drivers, is there any way to use a USB to get them on to the laptop?

Thanks in advance!

edit: It also says "media test failure, check cable" on boot, is that relevant?

Comment: If you are having problems with drivers unrelated to the disk, then go to the Toshiba site, find the drivers for your machine, download and install them.  From your description, nothing went wrong, you just haven't finished.  The disk knows nothing about your hardware. http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=3335718

Comment: I'll look for the network driver first so I can get the others automatically, or would you recommend I find them all manually?

Comment: Ive filtered the downloads based on "WiFi", "Windows 7 64bit" and "Drivers" but there are still like 7 to choose from!

I'm thinking "Intel Wireless LAN Driver", but I'm not sure. Do they all do the same general job or do you need a specific one?

For the record I recently had to swap the motherboard, this is the current motherboard I am running: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/H000032290-Toshiba-Motherboard-Satellite-L775-Intel-Laptop-S989-69N0Y3M1Eb01-01-/271178546376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely the drivers and you need to get the latest version. You can do this by figuring out for example your network cards name. Then type the name in to google followed by `driver download` Once you have done this click on one of the sites and download the driver. Then just install it like you would any program.

Comment: Sorted it now, cheers